# How to log in with the native YouTube app?

Tags: iphone, appletv, login, youtube

I created a new YouTube account to use functions like "watch later" on my iPhone4, my PC and my AppleTV2. But if I try to log in with this account on my iPhone and the native YouTube app, I always get the error message that the username and/or the password are wrong. I used as username the email address I used to create the YouTube/Google account and which I use to log in the web interface.

What I'm missing? I'm sure that the credentials I use are correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try logging in with your YouTube username, not your e-mail address. You can see your username when logging in from a regular computer in the top right corner.

Comment: Thx, this seams to be the problem. After creating the account I didn't have a username. The username must be created by preparing the account for usage on a mobile device. After I did that, I successfully logged in. On my iPhone and on AppleTV.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. Since I have signed up for 2-step verification I must use not my YouTube psw, but a application-specific password.

You can generate an application-specific password on your Authorizing applications and sites page using a desktop.

http://support.google.com/youtube/bin/answer.py?hl=no&answer=184968

Remember to use your email address, not you username.

Worked for me. :)